# Is there any way to get filename of the test within jest hooks?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Based on https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string, in my jest config I have
`"testEnvironment": "<rootDir>/scripts/testEnvironment.js"`. This testEnvironment.js file contains custom class with setup(), teardown() and handleTestEvent() methods.

Is there any way to get file name from one of the jest hooks, like `run_describe_start`, `test_start` or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [the same reference section](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string), environment class receives full path to test file:

```
class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context);
    this.testPath = context.testPath;
    ...
}
```

Filename can be extracted as

```
this.testFile = path.basename(this.testPath);
```

When assigned in a constructor, it becomes available in other methods.